# How to force ListView Columns to use Bindings for Width

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I created a ListView with 3 Columns, that stores a splitted log in it (My last question).

The Column for Date/Time gets it's size by a Double in my ViewModel. I also added a button that changes this size.

Normally it's set to "Double.NaN" for Autosize, but when you deactivate that button, the width is set to 0. That works fine, but when I resize the column manually, it won't change it's size anymore, even tho the binding value changes.

This is the code in my ListView.

```
private void HideDate(object obj)
    {
        // FillListView(false);
        DateWidth = 0;
    }

    private void ShowDate(object obj)
    {
        // FillListView();
        DateWidth = Double.NaN;
    }
```

I use a Messenger to trigger these methods, it works fine. This is my xaml for the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogEventList}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date/Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Width="{Binding DateWidth}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category}" Width="Auto" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Event" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Event}" Width="Auto" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Can I somehow tell the ListView to use DateWidth whenever it changes, as it seems to get another unchangeable property on a manual resize

Comment: DateWidth is a ViewModel property or it is present in the model? And where do you have the show/hide methods?

Comment: DateWidth is in the ViewModel, along with the Methods

Comment: So what you expect here is to notify DateWidth property when you manually change the width of column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a value on a property that will effectively overwrite any binding on that property.  Unless the property is marked to bind twoway by default or you bind twoway.

[Further explanation and example code](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30640.wpf-tips-the-mystery-of-the-lost-binding.aspx)

When the user drags a column I should think that process sets a value on width. Which will have the effect explained above.

The first thing to try is changing your binding to:

```
Width="{Binding DateWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You haven't explained your viewmodel fully so other changes might be necessary to make your app behave as expected.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!